# IE 8 Bug not displaying background

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

A bit of a strange one. The background image (or even when I add a color) to the header  on the website, that contains the menu items will not be displayed in IE8. It seems to work on Chrome and Firefox however in IE8 it does not display. The Url is http://www.esfdev.co.uk/emmanuel/ any help will be greatly appreciated.

CSS is below.

```
  div#header {
    background-image: url("./images/headerBg.png") !important;
    background-position: center bottom;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    height: 93px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10 !important;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I've tried this in both ie8 & Firefox, and it appears to be working in both for me at least?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/  and attempt to replicate the issue?  Off the top of my head I can't see any errors and don't see why it shouldn't work.

Comment: Hi Matt, I tried it IE tester and I was not able replicate the error, however I have seen it occur on two machines. I have checked if compatibility mode is selected which it is not. This is really puzzling.

Comment: Were these machines Windows XP?  I've seen IE8 behave differently in various environments.

Comment: Hi Myles, both Windows XP.